# NavigationBar not appearing with TTThumbsViewController in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, three20, ttthumbsviewcontroller

I'm trying to put a TTThumbsViewController inside a UITabBarController, but when I do, the TTThumbsViewController's NavigationBar doesn't show. There is just blank space where the NavigationBar should be. I've loaded just the TTThumbsViewController by itself, and the NavigationBar loads just fine. I'm sure I've just missed a setting, but I can't figure out what it is.

Here is what I'm doing to create the UITabBarController and the TTThumbsViewController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    ThumbsViewController *thumbsViewController = [[ThumbsViewController alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem *thumbsTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thumbs" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] tag:Thumbs];
    thumbsViewController.tabBarItem = thumbsTabBarItem;
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:thumbsViewController, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading the TTThumbsViewController from a UITabController, you need to create the UINavigationController yourself.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    ThumbsViewController *thumbsViewController = [[ThumbsViewController alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem *thumbsTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thumbs" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] tag:Thumbs];
    thumbsViewController.tabBarItem = thumbsTabBarItem;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ThumbsViewController] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I wired that in, and the navigation bar appeared, but now the TabBar is not showing.

Comment: hmm. ideally you should use the TTNavigator to load a TTUITabController, such as in TTNavigatorDemo sample app

Comment: Had to also set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to NO in my ThumbsViewController, but your solution fixes my problem. Thank you.